# Cordova healthkit plugin functions for iOS are returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to use the [cordova-plugin-health](https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health) plugin for a phonegap app I am working on. Whenever I use the app every plugin works but this one. I am using the phonegap mac app to test on an iPhone 6s.

Steps I have taken:

1. Installed plugin with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-health --variable HEALTH_READ_PERMISSION='App needs read access' --variable HEALTH_WRITE_PERMISSION='App needs write access'` also I did `cordova platform add ios`
2. Used `navigator.health.requestAuthorization` later on tried `window.plugin.health.requestAuthorization` my ide WebStorm was able to detect the second but not the first.

Is there anything I missed/can I use this plugin using the phonegap mac app?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean to say  in iOS, navigator.health is not working but window.plugin.health is working?

Comment: Both are not working.... but window.plugin.health is being detected by me IDE WebStorm... but that may not matter just pointing out the steps I took.

Comment: so what exactly is the issue now? what resolution is expected?

Comment: The window.plugin.health is running as undefined though it exists and it breaks my project because of that.

Comment: could you post the code that invokes the plugin? Is it inside deviceready event listener?

Comment: Not with my computer now but I will when I get home later today.

Comment: please update the question with code once you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap Developer App is a tool to easily preview your apps.
Phonegap Developer App is a Cordova app itself, that loads your app code from a local web server.
The thing about the Phonegap Developer App is, as it's a precompiled app, it can only run the plugins that were included on the Phonegap Developer App at the moment of the build.
That means, most 3rd party plugins (like the heathkit one) won't work as they are not included in the Phonegap Developer App.

What you can do is to run your app in your device instead of previewing it.

To do it, run, with the Phonegap CLI installed and your device plugged in:

`phonegap run ios`

If you have Cordova CLI installed, this should also work

`cordova run ios`.

Comment: Hi, Hope doing good. sorry to ask this as i dont have much expertise on phonegap tools. You mean to say we cant add any 3rd party plugin as we do in cordova CLI in this case?

Comment: You can add it, but it will only work if you run the app with Phonegap CLI. But as the OP is using the Phonegap Developer App, he is not running his app, just seeing how it will look like when he actually run it.