# Cordova: fcmPlugin.getToken is not a function

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin, phonegap-cli, phonegap

I am using Phonegap cli version 6.5.0 on Windows. I am trying to develop for Android Platform.

```
I am trying to make push notifications work through cordova-plugin-fcm plugin.
I have followed the installation gude at: https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm.</br>

But when I am running my code, I am getting following error:-
**I/chromium(19489): [INFO:CONSOLE(487)] "Uncaught TypeError: fcmPlugin.getToken is not a function", source: file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/index.html (487)**

My source files:
```

**index.html**

```
    <html> 
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>HK</title>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/FCMPlugin.js"></script>
    <script>
     function onDeviceReady () {
        console.log("Calling onDeviceReady()");
        var fcmPlugin = new FCMPlugin();
        fcmPlugin.getToken(function(success)
        {console.log("success");
        },
         function(error)
         { console.log("error");
         });
     </script>
    </br>
```

**js/FCMPlugin.js**

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
function FCMPlugin() { 
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: is created");
}

// SUBSCRIBE TO TOPIC //
FCMPlugin.prototype.subscribeToTopic = function( topic, success, error ){
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: subscribeToTopic");
    exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'subscribeToTopic', [topic]);
}
// UNSUBSCRIBE FROM TOPIC //
FCMPlugin.prototype.unsubscribeFromTopic = function( topic, success, error ){
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: unsubscribeToTopic");
    exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'unsubscribeFromTopic', [topic]);
}
// NOTIFICATION CALLBACK //
FCMPlugin.prototype.onNotification = function( callback, success, error ){
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: onNotification");
    FCMPlugin.prototype.onNotificationReceived = callback;
    exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'registerNotification',[]);
}
// TOKEN REFRESH CALLBACK //
FCMPlugin.prototype.onTokenRefresh = function( callback ){
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: onTokenRefresh");
    console.log("got fcm tokenRefreshs");
    FCMPlugin.prototype.onTokenRefreshReceived = callback;
}
// GET TOKEN //
FCMPlugin.prototype.getToken = function( success, error ){
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: getToken");
    console.log("got fcm token");
    exec(success, error, "FCMPlugin", 'getToken', []);
}
// DEFAULT NOTIFICATION CALLBACK //
FCMPlugin.prototype.onNotificationReceived = function(payload){
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: onNotification Received");
    console.log("Received push notification")
    console.log(payload)
}
// DEFAULT TOKEN REFRESH CALLBACK //
FCMPlugin.prototype.onTokenRefreshReceived = function(token){
    console.log("FCMPlugin.js: onTokenRefreshReceived");
    console.log("Received token refresh")
    console.log(token)
}
// FIRE READY //
exec(function(result){ console.log("FCMPlugin Ready OK") }, function(result){ console.log("FCMPlugin Ready ERROR") }, "FCMPlugin",'ready',[]);

console.log("FCMPlugin.js: came here");

var fcmPlugin = new FCMPlugin();
module.exports = fcmPlugin;

After searching through net, I was not able to resolve on my own. Can someone please point out , what mistakes I am doing? as I am pretty new to it.
```

Also if someone has a working code example on cordova-plugin-fcm, that would be a great help.
    Thanks,

Comment: use this plugin for firbase *cordova-plugin-firebase and after adding this u need to login in the firebase site and download the google-services.json file and put it in your root folder and below is the code for the  cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: `window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function (token) {
            // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
            navigator.notification.alert(token);
        }, function (error) {
            navigator.notification.alert(error);
        });`

Comment: `window.FirebasePlugin.onTokenRefresh(function (token) {
            // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
            console.log(token);
        }, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });`

Comment: `window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function (notification) {
            console.log(notification);
        }, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });`  if u follow the above instructions and apply these it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try now to see if it works

Comment: please mark it if is useful

Comment: @Madpop, When I am calling window.FirebasePlugin.getToken I am getting following error:-  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
 'getToken' of undefined".   I am using command "phonegap serve" on my pc , and phonegap app on my android mobile for the development. Is that setup fine?Can you please help with the error?

Comment: can u put ur code and share it  via github

Comment: @Madpop please find it here:- https://github.com/amol-beast/app/blob/master/

Comment: how are you testing the app?

Comment: @jcesarmobile . On my pc I have "phonegap serve" running , and on Android I am using Phonegap developer app to test my app. Is that correct setup for the above issue?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, you can't run 3rd party plugins on Phonegap Developer app. See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088814/cordova-healthkit-plugin-functions-for-ios-are-returning-undefined/44156086#44156086